# Mocktesting RestTemplate using Mockito in Spring boot latest version

Tags: spring, spring-boot, mockito, resttemplate

I am using 1.3.3.RELEASE version of Spring Boot.

I am trying to unit test my service which uses RestTemplate to call a url for fetching html page.

This is the code

```
Mockito.when(restTemplate.exchange(  
Mockito.anyString(),  
Mockito.any(HttpMethod.class),  
Mockito.any(HttpEntity.class),  
Mockito.any(Class.class)))  
.thenReturn(new ResponseEntity<String>("",   
new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.OK));
```

But thenReturn part is having issues. What could be the right construction of ResponseEntity for getting an html page.

Appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: What's the error you get?

Comment: The error I get is  org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue: 
ResponseEntity cannot be returned by toString()
toString() should return String

Answer (score 0):

you need to mock out responseEntity
so:

```
ResponseEntity<String> mockResponse = mock(ResponseEntity.class);
when(mockResponse.getStatusCode()).thenReturn(HttpStatus.OK);
```

then like you did before:

```
when(mockRestTemplate.exchange(anyString(), anyObject(), anyObject(), eq(String.class)))
    .thenReturn(mockResponse);
```